# Spring boot hibernate version stuck to 4

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

i just noticed that my 1.5 spring boot project keep using hibernate 4 after updating. 
I'm using gradle :

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
}
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

springBoot {
    configurations {
    provided.all*.exclude group: 'javax.servlet'
}

dependencies {
//  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
//  compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul')
//  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
//  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.10.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security")
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-velocity')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-social-facebook')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38')
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // rxjava
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    compile group: 'io.reactivex', name: 'rxjava', version: '1.1.6'
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // retrofit
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'adapter-rxjava', version: '2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // JODATIME
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // VELOCITY
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    compile group: 'org.apache.velocity', name: 'velocity-tools', version: '2.0'
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // BRAINTREE paypal checkout solution
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.braintreepayments.gateway/braintree-java
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    compile group: 'com.braintreepayments.gateway', name: 'braintree-java', version: '2.73.0'
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // AWS cloud object storage use and others
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-context
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-aws-context', version: '1.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.259'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.11.259'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-core', version: '1.11.259'



}
}
```

THe question is, documentation says it now use hibernate 5.0 by default and when i'm reloading my project i keep having 4.3.11 for hibernate-core ...
If you guys knows, would be great...

edit 1 : i added the full gradle code. don't think this change something but

Comment: That is not your full `build.gradle`. Please post the remainder, or at least your dependencies section.

Comment: edited with full build

Comment: Run `./gradlew dependencies` to see what is pulling in the old dependency.

Comment: still having org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.11.Final instead of 5.0.X version

Comment: Well of course you have as that will only generate a report of which dependencies are being pullen in with which version.

Comment: yes, just i don't know why my version is stuck like that
I needs to upgrade it... :/

Comment: just found that my whole application stays in spring boot 1.3.3 even if i requested 1.5.10... seems like to be a gradle bug maybe. I will try to update my gradle version